# A guy who can steal people's identity and power - what is this anime?

Tags: dna2

Possibly a late 90's/early 2000's anime. Memory is really fuzzy, but it had this female character who was a time traveller/or from space/another dimension.

There was a villain who was able to shape shift. There was one scene where the bad guy changed into (either by accident or deliberate) the main character and tried to rape the main character's love interest by locking himself and her in a closet at the gym. When the bad guy tried to touch her, electricity was discharged from his hand which caused him to flee.

Last scene I remember was the main character furiously riding his bike to face off against the bad guy. The bad guy was in a mansion(?) and he apparently was stealing the life force/identity of several victims by squeezing their face with his palm.

Watched the whole thing in Japanese. No subtitles. Wonderful anime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could be [**DNA²**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA%C2%B2) you are talking about

[image: DNA^2]

The girl in question seems to be Tomoko and as soon as the villain Ryuji touches her, he changes to her I guess. I don't remember if the last line of sucking others life force. But the description brought back the scene from DNA². Check out *episode 10* of the series and tell if it is the one you want. Hope this helps :D

Comment: This is it! Thank you. uhg the dub is so... glad I watched it in Japanese.

Comment: Glad i could help :D